# ionic2 get data from system browser

Tags: android, ios, mobile, browser, ionic2

I'm working on an Ionic 2 app which requires logging in using external link. For security reason I would prefer to open the link in system browser. After I open the link and login with username & password, a token will be returned in the body of the html. Is there a way to pass that token to my app? Or are there any other solutions to tackle this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Why not just send the credentials using the POST-method in that external link with an ajax-call in the ionic 2 app? Then you will receive the token inside your app?

Comment: have you considered redirecting on login success passing the token in the query string back in the url

Comment: @John In that way I will be able to intercept all the user's credentials. I don't want my users to have such worries. Opening an external link wouldn't have this security issue, I assume? Correct me if I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is extremely conceptual, but you could use the cordova plugin [inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) to open a browser inside the app, listen to the exit event to wait for the user to close the in-app browser, and there inject a script to retrieve the token from the html, something like:

```
inAppBrowserRef = undefined;

showLogin(url) {

    var target = "_blank";

    var options = "location=yes,hidden=yes";

    this.inAppBrowserRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);

    with (this.inAppBrowserRef) {
        addEventListener('exit', this.exitCallBack);
    }

}

exitCallBack(params) {

   captureToken = "return token = [[jquery to retrieve the token]]";



    this.inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({ code: captureToken}, this.executeScriptCallBack);

    this.inAppBrowserRef.close();

    this.inAppBrowserRef = undefined;

}

executeScriptCallBack(token) {

this.token=token;


}
```

Comment: sorry for my late replay. tried numerous times, when I use cordova InAppBrowser, i got reference error: can't find variable: cordova. I've checked my index.html, i have included cordova.js in the head. thanks!

Comment: Anyway, I used window.open(...) instead of cordova.InAppBrowser.open(...). Maybe one still need to install the inappbrowser beforehand? I'm not sure about this, but I have the inappbrowser plugin installed, and window.open() can open the page both in app or using system browser. Moreover, if one wanna navigate back to the app, use this plugin: [EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme), and you can find a walking-through [here](http://mcgivery.com/using-custom-url-schemes-ionic-framework-app/). But still, thank you @Manu for your help!